# Framework vulnerability

Tags: spring

We are using spring framework in our application. As we upgrade , sometimes a new vulnerability gets reported and we have to plan for upgrade again. Is there a way to deal with this? We don't want to upgrade spring 3 times in a year. Please suggest. We are using 5.3.31 currently and new vulnerability is reported against it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no good way to deal with this and it is a common problem across all frameworks and all products.  There is a choice to be made. Do you want to keep a high security hygiene? Or, do you want to run at some risk?

- You could opt not to upgrade and risk that the vulnerability could be exploited within your application, product.
- You could endure the pain of constantly keeping your framework, dependencies up to date to manage that risk.  Also note in most causes vulnerability fixes by Spring will go into patches or minor fixes.  If you are making upgrades to patched versions or minor release versions, there will really be minimal impact to any provided functionality from the framework.  The risk of having a regression as a result of the upgrade is extremely low.  Also, if you have a good automation suite in place for regression then you can minimize the costs of upgrades greatly.  If you do not have a good automation regression suite, then you may want to make some investment in that area to help preserve a good security hygiene for your application/product.

Comment: OP's approach speaks volumes. 5.3.x in 2024. Your 2nd bullet point is the way to go. I like to make it a WEEKLY ritual to upgrade all dependencies to latest on Friday mornings. It doesn't require any "planning" as OP suggests. 99% of dependency upgrades are NO OPs. If you wait 5 yrs between the time you touch dependencies, you might as well throw out your project and start from scratch. You'll never upgrade it without a TON of effort and hair pulling.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your response.